# does not find getRef(position) inside onCreateViewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am new to android studio , getRef(position)  inside onCreateViewHolder

getref is not recognised as command inside onCreateViewHolder

shows error is there any way around to solve the issue,trying to retrieve user info to another page but stuck with this issue

playing with this error for a while please do hep me soon

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKoUA.png)

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView myRecyclerView;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    List<MyDataGetSet> listData;
    FirebaseDatabase FDB;
    DatabaseReference DBR;
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar mToolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        mToolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.register_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("All Users");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        myRecyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.MyReclycler);
        myRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager LM= new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        myRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(LM);
        myRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        myRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));

        listData=new ArrayList<>();

        adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),listData);
        FDB=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        GetDataFirebase();

    }
    void  GetDataFirebase(){
        DBR=FDB.getReference("Users");

        DBR.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                MyDataGetSet data=dataSnapshot.getValue(MyDataGetSet.class);
                listData.add(data);
                myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
            {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String visit_user_id = childSnapshot.getKey();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }


    public  class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{
        private Context context;
        List<MyDataGetSet> listArray;

        public   MyAdapter(Context context,List<MyDataGetSet> List){
            this.context=context;
            this.listArray=List;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.itemview,parent,false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }



        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            MyDataGetSet data= listArray.get(position);
            holder.MyText.setText(data.getUser_name());
            holder.MyStatus.setText(data.getUser_status());


            Picasso.with(context).load(data.getUser_thumb_image()).into(holder.MyImage);



            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    String visit_user_id =getRef().getKey();
                    Intent profileIntend = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,ProfileActivity.class);
                     profileIntend.putExtra("visit_user_id",visit_user_id);
                    startActivity(profileIntend);
                }
            });
        }

        public  class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            TextView MyText;
            TextView MyStatus;
           CircleImageView MyImage;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);


                MyText=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextView);
                MyStatus=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextStatus);
                MyImage=(CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextImage);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return listArray.size();
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
String visit_user_id =getRef().getKey();
```

to

```
MyDataGetSet myDataGetSet = getItem(position);
```

Now having an object of `MyDataGetSet` class, you can get the key like this:

```
String visit_user_id = myDataGetSet.getVisitUserKey();
```

Assuming you have stored that key inside `myDataGetSet` object.